# The import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository can't be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring tool suite version 4. I have created a new spring boot project. Pom.xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>StudentCRUD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>StudentCRUD</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have created an entity class. No issue in that. But when I tried to create an interface extending the interface JpaRepository then the following import is not resolved:

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

I have done maven update several times and have clean-built the project also but no change. It will be really helpful if somebody could guide where I have done mistake?

Comment: Have you tried doing 'mvn clean install' your pom file looks ok, maybe the dependency is not yet downloaded. If you already downloaded yet this error still appear, try deleting the org/springframework/boot in your repository directory then do a 'mvn clean install' again. Hope this helps

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, could you find the solution bro ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a problem with your IDE? I have no problem importing JpaRepository with your pom.xml.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<Long, Object> {
}
```

Comment: This is resolved now. I deleted all the files within .m2/repositories folder and then did maven update. That solved the problem.

Comment: I'm currently having this problem but can't find a folder called .m2 - where was it for you?

Comment: On Mac and Linux in your users home directory, on Windows in your user's documents folder.